# Setting a dynamic spin value in excel (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I've spent way too much time trying to figure this out, I think I am just too unfamiliar with VBA.

I'm trying to make a spin SmallChange change dynamically with a cell's value.

So essentially I input some number into the target cell, and in another cell (preferably the same input one but I can't find a way to do that) gets outputted a value that changes with the spin clicks, and depending on the input cell's value, the SmallChange on the spin changes.

Example:

12.34 gets input into A1
Spin.SmallChange gets set to 5 (due to a series of if statements)
I spin that value up or down and a number gets outputted in A2 based on the spin amount
The spinner SmallChange should continue to check the output amount to see if it needs to change values
Sorry I am just realizing this is very difficult to put into words. I've tried doing it on paper, applying different loops, and I just can't figure it out. It seems so simple.

This is what I got so far (after many failed other lines of code)

```
Private Sub Spin2_Change()

Dim x 'input cell
Dim y 'output cell

'set x to input cell value
x = Sheet1.Range("A12")

'Setting spin value based on input number
If x >= 0 And x < 1 Then
    Sheet1.Spin2.SmallChange = 1

ElseIf x >= 1 And x < 20 Then
    Sheet1.Spin2.SmallChange = 5

ElseIf x >= 20 And x < 100 Then
    Sheet1.Spin2.SmallChange = 10

ElseIf x >= 100 And x < 500 Then
    Sheet1.Spin2.SmallChange = 50

ElseIf x > 500 And x < 1000 Then
    Sheet1.Spin2.SmallChange = 100

Else: Sheet1.Spin2.SmallChange = 500

End If



End Sub
```

Problem is that this only checks the first input cell which is not changing (because i can't figure out how). So when the output cell gets changed (which I can do with just an additional line of code) the spinner value doesn't change. Essentially I need to find out how to check, or make float values, or something?

Also note that the Spin.SmallChange values need to get divided by 100 to incorporate decimals to the input number.

Comment: You can link a spin object to a cell. Ref:https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/spin-button.html BTW, the condition of the last `ElseIf` should be `x >= 500 And x < 1000`

Comment: I ran into problems linking the spin value to the cell. For instance the spin value itself can't go negative, it instead jumps to like 65000. But if Spin.value is added to a cell, it works fine. Also, the main reason is that I need spin.value to be divided by a 100.. and vba doesn't like /= apparently, so i'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: You’d better add some screenshots to explain desired behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm after a little searching, I found that it can be achieve without using `Spin2_Change()` event, even without considering `Spin2.Value`

There are two spin button event called `SpinUp` and `SpinDown`. We can setup our own `smallchange` and do our things to any ranges we want.

```
Private Sub Spin2_SpinUp()
    changing Range("A1"), 1
End Sub

Private Sub Spin2_SpinDown()
    changing Range("A1"), -1
End Sub

Private Sub changing(ByVal target As Range, ByVal sign As Integer)
    Dim usrSmallChange As Double

    With target
        'setting usrSmallChange by conditions
        Select Case Abs(.Value)
            Case Is < 1
                usrSmallChange = 0.01
            Case Is < 20
                usrSmallChange = 0.05
            Case Is < 100
                usrSmallChange = 0.1
            Case Is < 500
                usrSmallChange = 0.5
            Case Is < 1000
                usrSmallChange = 1
            Case Else
                usrSmallChange = 5
        End Select

        .Value = .Value + usrSmallChange * sign
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is brilliant! I have no idea how you thought to directly bypass the _change event. Also using Case instead of if statements. Thanks a lot, this was really giving me a head ache.

Comment: Actually I was looking for an event which is triggered right before _change and sadly it doesn't exist. However I found http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Forms/Spinupeventprocedureforspinbutton.htm accidentally, making me realized that we can ignore the spin.value